Reading shadowed src/main/properties data file from test
Standard Maven project configuration, where resources are actually in src/main/resources/ and the abbreviated test data is kept in src/test/resources.
I'm trying to add a test that wants to verify info from say data.cfg in main, not the shorter version we use for testing. Basically, post compilation this will reside in classes/data.cfg while current test is loading from classpath and reading the version from test-classes/data.cfg.
Is there a way to load the original file with minimal other code or config changes?
Options I'd prefer to avoid:

Rename the test version and ensure current tests using this renamed option (so loading from classpath should fall back to main version)
Configure maven-resources plugin to make a copy of original under different name just for the verification test.


Got the solution while explaining the problem here :), figured I would still post and answer since I couldn't find it from searching earlier.
Just need to load resources from ../classes/data.cfg instead of the current data.cfg (which will read from test-classes/data.cfg).

For Class.getResource, Class.getResourceAsStream, ClassLoader.getResource, ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream, and Module.getResourceAsStream, use of .. is not supported.  Just because it happens to work for you today, doesn’t mean it will work in future versions of Java.  You may want to change the design of the class so that data.cfg is the default resource path, but that path can be changed using a method.
